# Kernel of Brauer characters

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I have learned ordinary representation theory of finite groups. I just started to study modular representation theory of finite groups. Unlike the ordinary representation theory, I find that basically there is no results on the kernel of Brauer characters while reading the textbook "Characters and Blocks of Finite Groups" by Navarro. **So, I am wondering why? My understanding is that, unlike kernel of complex characters, kernel of a Brauer character is complicated. Am I right?**

Here is two specific questions:

(1) For an irreducible $p$-Brauer character $\varphi$ of $G$, assume that there exists $\chi \in \mathrm{Irr}(G)$ such that $\chi^0=\varphi$ (here I use the notation introduced by Navarro).
Then we know that $\ker(\chi)\subseteq \ker(\varphi)$. However, is it always true that $\ker(\chi)= \ker(\varphi)$?

(2) For two distinct irreducible $p$-Brauer character $\alpha$, $\beta$ of $G$, we know that $\ker(\alpha+\beta)\subseteq \ker(\alpha)\cap \ker(\beta)$. However, is it always true that $\ker(\alpha+\beta)= \ker(\alpha)\cap \ker(\beta)$?

For (1), it is in general not true that $\ker(\chi)= \ker(\varphi)$.
For example, $G=\mathrm{GL}(2,3)$, $p=2$, $\chi$ is a linear character of $G$ having determinantal order $2$, so, $\varphi=\chi^0=1_{G^0}$.
However, $\ker(\chi)=G'\subset G=\ker(\varphi)$.

For (2), it is not true that $\ker(\alpha+\beta)= \ker(\alpha)\cap \ker(\beta)$.
For example, $G=\langle g\rangle\cong C_2$ and $\mathfrak{X}$ is a $GF(2)[G]$-representation such that $\mathfrak{X}(g)=e_{11}+e_{12}+e_{22}$ and $\mathfrak{X}(1)=e_{11}+e_{22}=I_2$.
Since $G\cong C_2$, $G$ has the unique irreducible $2$-Brauer character $1_{G^0}$,
$\mathfrak{X}$ affords the Brauer character $2\cdot 1_{G^0}$.
However, $\ker(2\cdot 1_{G^0})=\ker(\mathfrak{X})=1\neq G=\ker(1_{G^0})\cap \ker(1_{G^0})$.

Any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: The cyclic group of order $2$ and $p=2$ is a counterexample to (1). So what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks very much! I just want to know why I barely see people using kernel of Brauer characters in textbooks and papers? @DavidA.Craven

Comment: It's fundamental to the proof of the Brauer-Suzuki theorem.

Comment: Could you explain more? @DavidA.Craven

Comment: The proof of Brauer-Suzuki uses modular characters and aims to show that a specific element of order 2 lies in the kernel of a Brauer character.

Comment: Thanks very much! @DavidA.Craven